# Make async node script run forever

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, task

I searched a lot, but have not found the specific solution to my problem yet.
I have an async function that polls a database as node script that runs forever when using node 12, but in v14 the implementation changed and it closes immediately after running once.

```
(async function pollDatabase() {
    const db = new Db();

    return async.forever(async function (pollFn) {
 
        const query = "SELECT * FROM templates WHERE data->>'isProcessed'='0' LIMIT 1;";
        const templates = await db.query(query);

        if (!templates || !templates.length) {
            setTimeout(pollFn, 1000);
            return;
        }

        await doSomethingWithTemplateAndReExecuteThisFunction(templates[0], pollFn);
    });
})();
```

The weird thing is that for example an express server just stays running, but I have not figured out yet how that works. I was not planning to convert this background script to a server. Any thoughts on what would be the best way to make this run forever as some kind of background task? At the moment it is a docker container containing just this script.

Comment: Have you considered to use [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)?

Comment: Yes we have used that in the past and now just use a docker container with restart-always, but the idea is that it actually never stops and every second polls the database. And it works perfectly, but only when using Node 12 and not anymore when using Node 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself in the end. I don't know exactly why it happened with the switch to Node 14, but the combination of an outdated `pg-promise` and `bluebird` library seems to have been the culprit. I guess it probably has to do with the way Promises are now handled in Node 14.

Old versions:
`pg-promise@3.2.6` and `bluebird@2.10.2`

New versions:
`pg-promise@^10.9.4` with the native Promise implementation

Comment: Your assumption about Promise is likely invalid. But `pg-promise` version would be relevant, as it is updated to accommodate new NodeJS releases. You should at least include the version details of what you had, to consider this an answer.

Comment: Wow, those versions are from prehistoric times. It is no wonder they didn't work in the new NodeJS.